# Are the EF 6 (code first) able to use the default schema associated to the current database user?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

It's good to know that there's a HasDefaultSchema method supported in EF 6 so I can set what schema the EF can use. However, I wonder is it possible to make EF eliminate the schema prefix when generating SQL statement ( for example, generating "select * from TableA" instead of "select * from dbo.TableA" ) so that the database engine will use the default schema associated to the current database user.

I have several database users and each of them has a unique schema set as their default schema respectively. I think I can get correct data of each users respectively with their particular user name, password and the same SQL statement "SELECT * FROM TableA".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("")` results in a schema name starts with "CodeFirst".